# Locating XML Elements by Attribute Value in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"standalone="yes"?>
<WorkItem TimeZone="Mountain Standard" Offset="-07:00:00">
 <RevisionFields>
  <Field ReferenceName="OriginalTestEstimate" Name="Estimated Test" Type="Double">
     <Value>5</Value>
  </Field>
  <Field ReferenceName="RemainingDevWork" Name="Remaining Dev" Type="Double">
     <Value>9</Value>
  </Field>
  <Field ReferenceName="RemainingTestWork" Name="Remaining Test" Type="Double">
     <Value>5</Value>
  </Field>
 ...
```

A TFS service that I am calling gives it to me as an `XmlDocument` object.  I am trying to access the `Value` parts of the fields.  I can use `workItem["WorkItem"]["RevisionFields"]` to get to the array of all the fields, but when I try to get at a specific field using this notation I get stuck.

Since the "Name" is set I tried using that (ie `workItem["WorkItem"]["RevisionFields"]["Remaining Test"]` but that just returns null.

What do I need to do so I can get directly at the values in the fields? (I would prefer to not have to iterate all of the fields.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use XPath to retrieve the node:

```
/WorkItem/RevisionFields/Field[@Name='Remaining Test']/Value
```

Look at the [`SelectSingleNode()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx) (and the [`SelectNodes()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx)).

Comment: You're on the right "path", but this is still going to return an XmlNodeList.

Comment: @harpo: `SelectSingleNode` returns an `XmlNode`. Apart from that, I don't see what's wrong with an `XmlNodeList`. As far as I have understood, the OP just wants to avoid iterating the *uninteresting* nodes manually.

Comment: @Tomalak, my bad.  Somehow I read this as requiring an array of strings.

Comment: @harpo: Hm, might be. The question is not really clear on this. OTOH, I think it's not really difficult to get from node to string.

Comment: Can you offer an full example?  I tried `workItem.SelectSingleNode("/WorkItem/RevisionFields[@ReferenceName='Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate']/Value").Value` and that gave me null.  I also tried just `workItem.SelectSingleNode(@"/WorkItem/RevisionFields")` in the watch list and that also returned null.  (I know the data is there because I can open the workItem in the watch and browse around to it.)

Comment: Turns out the XPath should have been /WorkItem/RevisionFields **/Field** [@Name='Remaining Test']/Value

Comment: @Vaccano: Absolutely. This was my bad, sorry. I'll correct the answer.